# How do I query for records with multiple values for the last column in a compound GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

Given data that looks similar to this:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| country | city      | district |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| Japan   | Tokyo     | 1        |
| Japan   | Tokyo     | 1        |
| Japan   | Tokyo     | 2        |
| China   | Shanghai  | A        |
| China   | Shanghai  | A        |
| China   | Shanghai  | A        |
| China   | Beijing   | X        |
| China   | Beijing   | Y        |
| China   | Beijing   | Z        |
| India   | Mumbai    | 123      |
| India   | Mumbai    | 123      |
| India   | Mumbai    | 123      |
| India   | New Delhi | 321      |
| India   | New Delhi | 321      |
| India   | New Delhi | 321      |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

I know I can get the data visually by first doing:

```
SELECT * from that_table
GROUP BY country, city, district
```

and I'd get:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| country | city      | district |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| Japan   | Tokyo     | 1        |
| Japan   | Tokyo     | 2        |
| China   | Shanghai  | A        |
| China   | Beijing   | X        |
| China   | Beijing   | Y        |
| China   | Beijing   | Z        |
| India   | Mumbai    | 123      |
| India   | New Delhi | 321      |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

where I can see that only Japan/Tokyo and China/Beijing have multiple values for District.  However, I have a huge source of data and I'd like to do that in SQL.

How do I form the SQL query to get all Country/City combinations with multiple Districts?

The output I'd like to achieve is:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| country | city      | district |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| Japan   | Tokyo     | 1        |
| Japan   | Tokyo     | 2        |
| China   | Beijing   | X        |
| China   | Beijing   | Y        |
| China   | Beijing   | Z        |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Why does the source data have so many duplicate records in it?  Saying something three times (such as <India, New Delhi, 321>) doesn't make it any more true.

Comment: In your case select * is very bad, especially with a group by.  I rarely use select *, I only use it to query for tables for information, never in real code.

Comment: I have no control over the source data.  The data comes from the database of an old application which I only have read-only access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM foo a
  JOIN (
    SELECT country, city
    FROM (SELECT distinct country, city, district FROM foo)
    GROUP BY country, city
    HAVING count(country) > 1) b
  ON a.city = b.city AND a.country = b.country
GROUP BY a.country, a.city, a.district
```

Result:

```
COUNTRY CITY    DISTRICT
Japan   Tokyo   2
Japan   Tokyo   1
China   Beijing Z
China   Beijing Y
China   Beijing X
```

Comment: After verifying each of the suggested answers, only this answer provided me with the correct output.  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT country, city, district FROM that_table tt1
              JOIN (
                    SELECT country, city  from that_table
                    GROUP BY country, city
                    HAVING count(1) > 1) tt2
              ON tt1.city = tt2.city
              AND tt1.Country = tt2.country
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition that there must be at least one district for the same city with a different name:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM YourTable a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable b
    WHERE a.Country = b.Country
    AND a.City = b.City
    AND a.District <> b.District
)
```